# TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'

Tags: python, discord.py

Yo tengo un bot de Discord en Python y funcionaba bien. Hoy me advirtieron de que no estaba encendido y al abrir la terminal de Python me encuentro con un error (habia corrido el codigo antes y andaba de maravilla). Al intentar reiniciar el bot salio el error de nuevo.
Este es el error:
`TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'`
Se que mi codigo no es, siempre corrio perfecto y no le hice ninguna modificacion.

Comment: ¿En qué archivo y linea te da el error?

Comment: no me especifica una linea, aparte por lo que acabo de entender necesito actualizar discord.py, intente desinstalarlo y reinstalarlo desde pip pero me sigue tirando error

Comment: Si no compartes tu código y/o el error completo es muy difícil ayudarte. Si el bot nunca se enciende, el problema debería estar en la línea donde instancias el bot o en otra variable que tengas definida de forma global

Answer (score 0):

Buenas me sucedió lo mismo justamente hace un momento, pruebe estos comandos los cuales me sirvieron para arreglar dicho error:

1. **apt-get update && apt-get upgrade**
2. **python3 -m pip install -U discord.py**

Answer (score -1):

He encontrado una solucion, desinstala mediante pip discord.py y vuelve a instalarlo. Necesitas la versions 1.3.4 o superior para que funcione.

Comment: lo acabo de hacer y me sigue tirando el error.